# can i make javascript persist after a refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

In my form i need to select an item (which is a div with text or an image) and i do set the id of a hidden input via jquery live click event.

In the case the user has logged out or session has expired he must go back and refresh the page (after logging in). After a refresh firefox keeps all input data (textarea, text, select, etc). BUT the value i set in the hidden input is reset back to 0 and the user must click the item again.

How can i make javascript remember after a page refresh? Everything else is remembered after a refresh, its natural for the user to expect this is too instead of being annoyed every time some error occurs with his entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use type="text" and style="display:none" instead of type="hidden"

Comment: genius. You beat out all the other answers hands down.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo: even if its browser-dependent it will be consistent since all or no data will be available. (unless some browsers purposely ignore text fields set by javascript which i dont know why they would)

Answer (score 2):

You can store some information in a cookie, or in the `window.location.hash` key or in the `window.name`

All these values will be kept when you refresh.

Comment: interesting. Would it have a weird side effect when the user clicks something? (when i set the hash?). I may do this.

Comment: confirmed. when doing this in firefox and chrome it jumps when items are clicked.

Comment: If you use already the hash for something else, it's better to use the other options.

Comment: hmm i think i understand what your saying. if i am using the hash? you mean if i using the val as an id? i am storing ids in there which now makes sense that its jumping to it. i forgot, +1

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you can use `cookies` to store the selected value. Don't forget to clear once the form has been processed.

**EDIT 1**

If you have a situation when the user can submit it more time, you must prefix each cookie with an ID to denote the current form.
When the form is presented to the user first time, make a hidden field having the timestamp stored in it (This can be done on the server side). Then you can use this timestamp for the cookie prefix, so you will have cookies for the form that has been generated, and another timestamp for the 2nd form the user works with. You will have independent cookies for each form you open in your browser.
When you submit the page, the timestamp is sent to the server and you can setup cookies. If the user hits the browsers back button, it will go back to a form, where you already have the timestamp in your form's html source, so it will load the cookies for that form.

Comment: answer has already but accepted but what if the user submits 2 pages? only the most recent will have the correct info.

Comment: See my edit to the question of using timestamp or microtime to store cookies against the current form.

Comment: i like it. But i see ONE last problem. If i hit refresh wouldnt i lose the timestamp? Theres no way for the server to know which page/form i refresh and would replace the timestamp. If its possible to hack the refresh button then i could add the timestamp to the url (or use the '#hash-data'). But hacking the refresh button feels like a hack and is probably browser dependent?

Comment: If user hits refresh, he wants to get refresh. I think it's too much you want. You simply can't overwrite how a browser works.